# pass NSArray to next viewcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, xcode8, ios10, apple-developer

New to swift, hope I will get my answer. I need to pass NSArray to next view controller and in random order when button is pressed. I have UILabel and one variable declared in second view controller and segue seems working. Only peoblem is it does not pass any value. Here is my code.

```
    @IBAction func ressedbutton(_ sender: Any) {

    let quotes: NSArray = ["Quote 000", "Quote 001", "Quote 002"]

    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(quotes.count)

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    let QuoteString = quotes.object(at: randomNumber)

   // self.resul.text = QuoteString as? String





    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showresult", sender: QuoteString)

    let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "result") as! result

    myVC.stringPassed =
        (QuoteString as? String)!



}
```

and code for second view is

class result: UIViewController {

```
var stringPassed = ""
@IBOutlet weak var ResultLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ResultLabel.text = stringPassed
```

I think my problem is in myvc.stringpassed=...? How to pass the arry I have and in randomly?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: set breakpoints in "prepareForSegue", you are setting this string too late

Comment: Do you want to pass array with seague or without seague ?

Comment: with segue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass that value with `sender` in `performSegue` and after that access that value in `prepare(for:sender:)` and pass the value to destinationController.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showresult", sender: QuoteString)
```

Now use this `sender` argument in `prepare(for:sender:)`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? result, let data = sender as? String {
        vc.stringPassed = data
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said still the second view is empty. Here is my code for the second view if it helps.                                                                        class result: UIViewController {
    
    var stringPassed = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var ResultLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        ResultLabel.text = stringPassed

Comment: @VisiogamesLtd Edit your question with your current code and with your result controller

Comment: Yes I did now. Thanks

Comment: @VisiogamesLtd I have told your to pass `QuoteString` with sender when you call `performSegue` and you are still passing the `sender` so simply replace your line `performSegue(withIdentifier: "showresult", sender: sender)` with my one `performSegue(withIdentifier: "showresult", sender: QuoteString)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that but yes I did use your code. It shows completely blank in next view.

Comment: @VisiogamesLtd Then edit your question with you code because from your current code from question it is looks like you are still passing sender as value not QuoteString

Comment: Now it is fixed.

Comment: @VisiogamesLtd Is it working now ? Are you getting string on next controller ?

Comment: No sir, It shows no error and build normally but the next view is still empty

Comment: @VisiogamesLtd Put the break point in `prepare(for:segue:)` and check this line `vc.stringPassed = data` is executing or not

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just made one silly mistake. Your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) method to assign data to toViewController.UIStoryboardSegue object segue have properties like identifier ,destination and source.

In this method first you check the identifier,if it matches cast the destination controller to your custom view controller and assign the data to the view controller object.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showresult"{
        if let toViewController = segue.destination as? result {
            vc.stringPassed = QuoteString
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said still the second view is empty. Now I have added the code for second view also if it helps. Thanks

Comment: Are you implemented prepare method in your first view controller?

Comment: Yes I did implemented in first view

Answer (score 0):

try this way remove segue give Storyboard ID to your view controller where u want to pass data and paste that same Storyboard Id below (YourIdentifier)

```
    @IBAction func ressedbutton(_ sender: Any) {

    let quotes: NSArray = ["Quote 000", "Quote 001", "Quote 002"]

    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(quotes.count)

    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    let QuoteString = quotes.object(at: randomNumber)

   // self.resul.text = QuoteString as? String

  let vc  = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"YourIdentifier") as! YourNextViewController


        vc.stringPassed = (QuoteString as? String)!


        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Have you read the op comment that he want to do with segue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868038/pass-nsarray-to-next-viewcontroller-in-swift/#comment74778935_43868038

Comment: I crashes with this style.

Comment: what is the reason for crash? may be You are not giving Identifier to you storyboard